# Efficiently sample vectors from numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, random, slice

I have a multidimensional numpy array `X` of `shape`: `(B, dim, H, W)` I would like to randomly sample `k` `dim`-dimensional vectors out of `X`.
I can get the sample indices from a `msk` of shape `(B, 1, H, W)`:

```
sIdx = random.sample((msk.flat>=0).nonzero()[0], k)
```

Equivalent sampling code using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) is:

```
sIdx = np.random.choice((msk.flat>=0).nonzero()[0], replace=False, size=(k,))
```

But how can I **efficiently** slice `X` according to the "flat" sampled indices `sIdx`?
That is, is there an efficient way to combine the random sampling of `msk` with the slicing of `X`?

Comment: Is `random` from module `random`? What's the shape of final output?

Comment: @Divakar yes, `sample` is from `random` module. The sampling can be replaced with `sIdx = np.random.choice((msk.flat>=0).nonzero()[0], replace=False, size=(k,))`

Comment: @Divakar the final output I expect to be of `shape` `k`-by-`dim`.

Comment: @NilsWerner thank you for the answer. I am trying to avoid `reshape` and `transpose` as much as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the respective indices for the rest of those three axes with [`np.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) from the flattened indices and simply index into `X` along those axes for the final output, like so -

```
I,J,K = np.unravel_index(sIdx, (B, H, W))
out = X[I,:,J,K]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to to "fuse" the "flat" sampling and the `unravel` to make this process even more efficient? That is, is there a way to directly sample the "unravel"ed indices?

Comment: @Shai I don't see any other way. We need `flat` to generate the linear indices for sampling. Now, `flat` is simply a view, so no additional memory required there, so should be pretty efficient.

Comment: Just tried to write up an answer without flattening the indices and yeah, I don't even want to submit because it's just too messy and confusing and doesn't improve the performance at all.

Comment: @DanielF well, thanks for the effort anyway! would you consider posting as a "negative" result?

Comment: It started out with `sIdx = random.sample(list(np.transpose((msk >= 0).nonzero())), k) ` and then even I got lost.  Problem is you have 4 indices going in and only need 3 indices coming out, and flattening is a much better way of doing that.